# The method '*' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: *(3.5)

Tags: flutter, dart

estoy creando una aplicación en flutter, he implementado mi sistema de medidas en base a las medidas de la pantalla del dispositivo y todo va correcto, ahora mi problema reside en que al crear mi ThemeData personalizado todo va bien hasta el momento en el que defino el tamaño de fuente a cada TextTheme. Tengo unos datos adicionales que les podria servir para encontrar este problema que me esta rompiendo la cabeza.

================= size_config.dart =================

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static double _screenWidth;
  static double _screenHeight;
  static double _blocWidth;
  static double _blocHeight;

  static double textMultiplier;
  static double imageSizeMultiplier;
  static double widthMultiplier;
  static double heightMultiplier;
  static bool isPortrait = true;
  static bool isMobilePortrait = false;

  void init(BoxConstraints constraints, Orientation orientation) {
    if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
      _screenWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
      _screenHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
      isPortrait = true;

      if (_screenWidth < 450) isMobilePortrait = true;
    } else {
      _screenWidth = constraints.maxHeight;
      _screenHeight = constraints.maxWidth;
      isPortrait = false;
      isMobilePortrait = false;
    }

    _blocWidth = _screenWidth / 100;
    _blocHeight = _screenHeight / 100;

    textMultiplier = _blocHeight;
    imageSizeMultiplier = _blocWidth;
    widthMultiplier = _blocWidth;
    heightMultiplier = _blocHeight;
  }
}
```

El problema esta en este archivo

================= size_config.dart =================

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:okrama/utilities/size_config.dart';

class AppTheme {
  AppTheme._();

  static const String titleFont = 'Raleway';
  static const String bodyFont = 'Open Sans';
  static const Color lightBackgroundColor = Colors.white;

  static double largeTextSize =
      (SizeConfig.textMultiplier * 3.5).roundToDouble();  // *****

  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    fontFamily: bodyFont,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: lightBackgroundColor,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
    textTheme: lightTextTheme,
  );

  static final TextTheme lightTextTheme = TextTheme(
    headline6: _headline6Style,
  );

  static final TextStyle _headline6Style = TextStyle(
    fontFamily: titleFont,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: largeTextSize,  // largeTextSize == null.
  );
}
```

Ahora explico, el problema que presenta es el siguiente

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
The method '*' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: *(3.5)
```

y solo aparece cuando en la variable _headline6Style, cuando fontSize: largeTextSize, en ese momento largeTextSize es igual a null, sin embargo, si fontSize: 30, largeTextSize es igual al resultado de la operación 3.5 * SizeConfig.textMultiplier

```
static final TextStyle _headline6Style = TextStyle(
        fontFamily: titleFont,
        color: Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: largeTextSize,  // largeTextSize == null.
      );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
static final TextStyle _headline6Style = TextStyle(
        fontFamily: titleFont,
        color: Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 30,  // largeTextSize == 25.0.
      );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SizeConfig.textMultiplier = 7.12
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro,pero no veo que llames al metodo init() que es el que da valor a largeTextSize cuando pones esto:

```
static double largeTextSize =
  (SizeConfig.textMultiplier * 3.5).roundToDouble();
```

Si no esta inicializada ,textMultiplier seria null.

Comment: Hola jose, tengo inicializada el metodo init en otro widget que no le tome mucha importancia al ponerlo en mi pregunta (Disculpa), pero mas o menos estaba leyendo que regresa null cuando mi metodo init no esta dentro del widget MaterialApp (esto al momento de definir un ThemeData) y esto es lo que me daba error y me retornaba un null, aun no lo tengo muy bien entendido pero he aprendido algo de este dolor de cabeza :) .